# How to increase paragraph space in a text view?

Tags: android

I want to increase the space between two paragraph in android studio. I searched in google and I found many solution but all about to line space only. But I want  paragraph space.

In my app I separate two paragraph with \n but my text view shows like this.

China's People Liberation Army (PLA) transgressed the Line of Actual Control (LAC) at least three times last month in the Uttarakhand state, according to sources quoted by news agency ANI.
The report further said that the Chinese troops crossed over as far as four kilometres into the Indian territory in Barahoti village in the Chamoli district of the state.

But I actually want like this

China's People Liberation Army (PLA) transgressed the Line of Actual Control (LAC) at least three times last month in the Uttarakhand state, according to sources quoted by news agency ANI.

The report further said that the Chinese troops crossed over as far as four kilometres into the Indian territory in Barahoti village in the Chamoli district of the state.

Is it possible???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use \n instead of /n

Comment: Use \n on the place of /n

Answer (score 0):

Your are using wrong line spacing element.It is not /n  but it is \n.Add the string resource to the strings.xml file like this,

```
  <string name="demo_summary"> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. \n It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</string>
```

It will show two paragraph with one line space.For two line space use double \n

Comment: @Prasin Welcome! If this answer is helpful you may mark it as accepted.It can be helpful for others also.Thank you...